# Setting state in array nested in object state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am thinking of a solution on how to upgrade a property in an object which is in array of objects. But the array itself is nested inside in state object. Any ideas on how to update the object and then the array of of objects itself?

Currently the problem is that, when it is setting the state, it returns "golfTeeSlotReservations is undefined"

Please, see my example below.

```
    this.state = {
       model: {
         golfTeeSlotReservations: [
           {id:1, partySize: 20, round: 1},
           {id:2, partySize: 30, round: 2}
         ]   
       }
    }

if (this.state.golfFirstRoundNewPartySize) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                model: {
                    ...prevState.model,
                    golfTeeSlotReservations: prevState.golfTeeSlotReservations.map(item => (
                        item.round === 1 ? Object.assign(item, { partySize: this.state.golfFirstRoundNewPartySize }) : item
                    ))
                }
            }))
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution ?

Comment: My bad, I edited my question. The problem is that it returns "golfTeeSlotReservations" is undefined

Comment: You are calling it with `state.golfTeeSlotReservations` while it should be `state.model.golfTeeSlotReservations`